# Computing FIR filter coefficients

Tags: filter-design, finite-impulse-response

I'm trying to understand the math behind FIR filter design. I'm focusing on the simple case of an ideal LPF with the following frequency domain behavior:

[image: eq1]

When the IDFT is applied, I end up with:

[image: eq2]

I select N (filter order) = 8, so my filter length = 9. Then, let n = n - N/2, yielding:

[image: eq3]

If I then evaluate h[n] for n = 0...8, I get a div/0 condition when n = 4, since (4 - 8/2) = 0.

How do I reconcile this? I can use a different type of filter with an even length, but I'd like to understand and be able to successfully compute both cases.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

\begin{align*}
h[n] &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}H(e^{j\omega})e^{j\omega n}d\omega \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\omega_c}^{\omega_c}e^{j\omega n}d\omega
\end{align*}

For $n=0$ you obtain

$$
h[0] = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\omega_c}^{\omega_c}d\omega = \frac{\omega_c}{\pi}
$$

which is also the limit of $\sin(\omega_c n)/\pi n$ for $n\to 0$.

Comment: ahhhh. so simple. thanks so much!